# Centering table caption not working

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions

I cannot make my table caption centered (it keeps staying on the left side) in a  two-column manuscript. Here is the code I am using:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{autart}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Nomenclature used in the model.} 
  \label{nomenclature}
  \vskip\baselineskip % Leave a vertical skip below the figure
  \begin{tabular}{|cc|} 
  \hline
          Col 1  &  Col 2          \\
          \hline
          1  &   4         \\
          2  &    5       \\
          3  &     6       \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ. Please also reveal whether the preamble of your document loads the `caption` package and, if so, the options employed with that package.

Comment: @Mico thanks, I edited the code. I hope that's what you asked for.

Comment: I think normally the caption goes after the table? If you don't use it as the package specify it may not work properly

Comment: @user202729 I tried changing caption's place but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @AminShn - The `autart` document class is not included automatically with TeXLive (one of the main TeX distributions). Is `autart.cls` available online somewhere?

Comment: @Mico It's here: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-automatica-ifac-journal/wxstjkyjmkmp

Comment: This is how your class defines tables, if you don't like it, why use it then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code is copied from the `autart.cls` file.

```
\long\def\@maketablecaption#1#2{\@tablecaptionsize
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hbox to \hsize{\parbox[t]{\hsize}{#1 \\ #2}}}
```

This typesets the caption in a box over the complete horizontal space. Therefore `\centering` has no effect for your caption.

You could change the code of the `autart.cls` file, but I would **not recommend** doing this, since the current style is probably required.

If you insist doing this, you could add the following to your preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\@maketablecaption#1#2{\@tablecaptionsize
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{#1. #2}
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize              % IF longer than one line THEN
    \unhbox\@tempboxa\par                   %   set as justified paragraph
  \else                                     % ELSE
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hbox to\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%   center single line.
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

The code is copied from `@makefigurecaption`. The caption will be centered if it fits on one line, otherwise it will be a justified paragraph. See the examples I provided.

[image: table output]

Comment: You don't need to explicitly change the cls file. You can just enclose them within `makeatletter...makeatother` in the preamble and add the code here.

Comment: @Imran thanks, I have updated to answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think the "Automatica" journal wants the table caption to be like this (left-aligned rather than centered) and it doesn't look awful to me when there is some text around it. An example:

[image]

Yet if you want to center the caption, you can insert the `\centering` command in the 2nd mandatory argument of the `parbox`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{autart}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

%--------------------------added---------------------------
\makeatletter
\long\def\@maketablecaption#1#2{\@tablecaptionsize
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hbox to \hsize{\parbox[t]{\hsize}{\centering#1 \\ #2}}}
\makeatother
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Nomenclature used in the model.} 
    \label{nomenclature}
    \vskip\baselineskip % Leave a vertical skip below the figure
    \begin{tabular}{|cc|} 
        \hline
        Col 1  &  Col 2 \\
        \hline
        1  &   4        \\
        2  &    5       \\
        3  &     6      \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]